# What is the right way to create a view in BigQuery for a table with an array column for consumption by PowerBi?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, view, powerbi

I have a table in BigQuery that contains, among other fields, an ID column and an array column.  Since bringing the table into PowerBi, the array is just some delimited strings that aren't terribly useful, so clearly, I'll need a view to base my PowerBi off of.  So, what is the right way to handle this so that the array data is useful in PowerBi?

My solution is to create 2 views, the first being a view for all the columns except the array column, and the second being a view the contains the ID, and the unnested array column, thus creating a one-to-many that can be joined to the first view if the user wants the array data, knowing that doing such a join will likely give them duplicates of the non-array data in the result.

Is there a better way?

Comment: who said you cannot have view with array column? you can!

Comment: True, it will let you save the view, but when I attempt to use the view and do a WHERE on one of the array values, I get the following error...
"Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRUCT<object STRING, balance_transaction STRING, created INT64, ...>>> at [2:19]"

Also, when using the view with PowerBi, the array data is just a delimited string, so not terrebly useful.

Comment: So, this is a totally different issue then! You should revisit your question!